# Can we deploy .NET microservice based app on normal windows server (with no containers)

Tags: .net, azure, docker, .net-core

I want to start building a new `.NET` applications based on Microservices Architecture, but currently the available `.NET` servers are not ready  for containers technology i.e. `Docker`, can we deploy an application built using `.NET Core 2.0` on the normal `.NET` environment that usually used to deploy a monolithic applications ?

Comment: Ah... sure. Did you have problems?

Comment: @nvoigt no .. I didn't start yet, I plan to start with currently available environment (normal IIS server) with intention in the fuAture to deploy it on container based environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Microservices** is not about technical details, but about design and architecture. A .NET Core app is a .NET Core app and will run on Windows, whether you split your logic in 200 micro services or build one single ugly blob. Technically, they all build the same type of assembly.

Comment: So in the future it is evry easy to move the 200 micro services into container-based env?

Comment: Depends on your container and whether you actually do it correctly. There should be no problem to develop locally for containers and then dump all your services in the same "container" (your big windows server) in the end. Microservices existed before ready-made containers.